# Let $x_1=\sqrt{2},\:x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2^{x_n}}$, $n\ge 1$. Use induction to show that $x_n \le2$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: solution-verification, induction

My thinking:

**Base Case:** $n=1$

$x_2 = \sqrt{2^\sqrt{2}} = 1.6325... \le 2$

**Inductive Hypothesis**:

Assume some $x_{k} = \sqrt{2^{x_{k-1}}} \le 2$

**Inductive Step**:

Consider $x_{k+1} = \sqrt{2^{x_k}}$

This is where I'm stuck.

I know since $x_k \le 2$, it intuitively makes sense that $2^{x_k} \le 4 \rightarrow$ $\sqrt{2^{x_k}} \le 2$.

Is this valid reasoning? If not, what would be the correct way of solving this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $f(x)=\sqrt{2^x}=\sqrt2^x$ is monotonically increasing, so if $x\le2$ then $f(x)\le\sqrt{2^2}=2$.